# How can I do port binding for Express, Socket.io, WebSocket?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, server, socket.io

Currently, `Express` server using `HTTPS` communication and `Socket.io` are using the same port `443`. However, it's necessary to apply the third-party project to the web server, so it's necessary to use the `WebSocket` package together.

I found the article below to find a way to use the same port `443` for `Express`, `Socket.io`, and `WebSocket` respectively, but I don't know if this is correct.

> Reference article URL : [Go to page](https://gir.me.uk/posts/socket.io-and-ws-server-on-the-same-port.html)

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
... Some register middleware

module.exports = app;
```

**bin/www**

```
const app = require('../app');
const https = require('https');
...
const server = https.createServer(options, app);
const io = require('socket.io)(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    ....
});

server.listen(443, '0.0.0.0');
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  The code you show in the bin/www code block will successfully use both socket.io and your Express server on the same 443 port.  Socket.io uses webSocket as its transport so that is also running on 443.

Comment: @jfriend00 To be precise, there is a part that communicates with `Socket.io` and there is a part that needs to send and receive `WebSocket` separately. Can I still communicate by switching to `WebSocket` in this case?

Comment: As best I know, you cannot easily use both plain webSocket and socket.io on the same port.  You'd have to somehow patch into socket.io's code that grabs a webSocket connection, figure out that the incoming connection is not meant for socket.io and redirect it to different code to handle it.  That's theoretically possible, but not easy.  99.999999% of developers would just run the webSocket or socket.io connection on a different port.  Your article purports to kind of show you how to differentiate an incoming socket.io connection from a plain webSocket connection.

Comment: @jfriend00 I understood what it means. So I think you need to think about how to send `WebSocket` data to `Socket.io`.

Comment: Socket.io already uses webSocket as its transport, but it requires a layer on top of that transport.  I'm going to leave this conversation because I simply don't understand what you're saying.  Good luck - hopefully someone else will come along to help that understands what you're saying.